# Typescript: take a type and return a union type in a generic interface

Tags: generics, typescript, interface, unions

Imagine a simple `CollectionStore` which has methods for creating and updating a record. `create()` accepts a set of attributes and returns the same set with `id` property added. `update` accepts the set of the same structure but requires the `id` property to be defined.

How do I express in Typescript that `create()` function accepts some type `T` and returns `T & {id: string}` ?

I would expect the pattern to be expressed like that:

```
interface CollectionStore<T> {
    updateRecord(T & {id: string}): void;
    createRecord(T): T & {id: string};
}
```

However the code above isn't valid. Please help =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in how you use the union type, but you failed to provide names for the functions params which is why you get the error, it should be:

```
interface CollectionStore<T> {
    updateRecord(record: T & { id: string }): void;
    createRecord(record: T): T & { id: string };
}
```

And then:

```
interface MyRecord {
    key: string;
}

let a: CollectionStore<MyRecord> = ...;

a.updateRecord({ key: "key", id: "id" });
a.createRecord({ key: "key" });
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20CollectionStore%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20updateRecord(record%3A%20T%20%26%20%7Bid%3A%20string%7D)%3A%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20createRecord(record%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%26%20%7Bid%3A%20string%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20MyRecord%20%7B%0A%09key%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20a%3A%20CollectionStore%3CMyRecord%3E%20%3D%20null%3B%0A%0Aa.updateRecord(%7B%20key%3A%20%22key%22%2C%20id%3A%20%22id%22%20%7D)%3B%0Aa.createRecord(%7B%20key%3A%20%22key%22%20%7D)%3B))

Another option you have is to just have a base interface for records in which the `id` property is optional:

```
interface Record {
    id?: string;
}

interface CollectionStore<T extends Record> {
    updateRecord(record: T): void;
    createRecord(record: T): T;
}
```

But then you lose the ability to enforce that `updateRecord` returns an object with an id.